# Media such as videos / GIF's do not run on Twitter in IE

Tags: twitter, tweet, internet-explorer

Whenever I view a tweet on Twitter that contains a GIF or a video, I get the following "error":

[image: Media could not be played]

This does not happen when I view the same tweets when I use Google Chrome to access Twitter.

Is there any changes I need to make in regards to any settings in IE11?

Answer (score 1):

This could be add-ons issue. Clear cache. Try with InPrivate window. Try to update Internet Explorer.

From [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2532294/videos-won-t-play-in-internet-explorer):

> When you experience problems playing videos in Internet Explorer, these problems may be caused by a number of different issues. Most video playback uses Adobe Flash, Microsoft Silverlight, or Java, and these platforms require Internet Explorer add-ons in order to play. By making sure that you have the latest updates installed for Windows, Internet Explorer, and any Internet Explorer add-ons, you can resolve most video playback problems.
>   To troubleshoot video playback problems in Internet Explorer, follow these steps. Test the playback behavior after each step until the issue is resolved.
>
> 1. Update Internet Explorer
> 2. Test the video in Compatibility View
> 3. Make sure that add-ons are installed and enabled
> 4. Update to the latest add-ons
> 5. Turn off ActiveX filtering and Tracking Protection

Seems this is a known issue, and Microsoft working on it. So troubleshoot from yourself and if still doesn't work, contact to Microsoft. This is nothing have to do with Twitter.

Have a look on these thread for more info:

- [The media could not be played](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/the-media-could-not-be-played/2910deb0-95ff-4a49-8d2d-0857d5d39513?auth=1)
- [IE11 Does not support video playback on Twitter videos](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/ie11-does-not-support-video-playback-on-twitter/b28019f1-f82b-41d2-aa94-50bb56c0d9a2)